# Software to test external hard disk sensors

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I need some software to test external hard disk sensors. My harddrive sometimes is detected when inserting in USB 3.0, sometimes its not detected in PC (light is off, fan runs).

I reached out to local Technician, he told me that it could be a problem with sensor, and he failed to open because of my warranty period of 3yrs. Its been 6 months I purchased this harddisk and I used it only thrice. As of now I couldn't reach out to Toshiba auth team for this issue. So I thought I can get the sensors tested with tools.

I used HDDscan tool to see S.M.A.R.T and other checks which shows me without any errors.

https://smarthdd.com/database/TOSHIBA-MQ04UBF100/JU0B0U/ this is the similar details of my harddisk

Can anyone suggest me the software to test external hard disk sensors?

Comment: When it comes to HDDs then SMART values and sensors is everything you can get as a normal user. Data recovery centers may have access to more detailed documentation of certain HDD models and thus may be able to test HDD components or sensors directly, but I don't thing regular users can get access to this documentation.

Comment: I agree with Robert here. But in case such software exists: What OS must it run on, and how much may it cost to be acceptable for you?